# How To Make Declarations of an Array type Class

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I am taking Data Structure Course, And I have a Question at the end of the Chapter that I couldn't solve.

```
class WeatherRecType {
    int AvgHiTemp;
    int AvgLoTemp;
    float ActualRain;
    float RecordRain;
}
```

Question:

> Declare a one-dimensional array, `WeatherListType` of `WeatherRecType` components, contains ten elements.

Answer:

```
WeatherRecType WeatherListType[] = new WeatherRecType[10];
```

---

Question:

> Assign the value 1.05 to the `ActualRain` field of the seventh record in `WeatherListType`.

Answer: ???

How to assign the value to the `ActualRain` in the Array `WeatherListType` field number 7?

I tried it like this, but it doesn't work:
[image: Problem Image]

---

The problem is solved, thanks to everyone who shared their knowledge with me.
Here is the correct answer:
[image: Correct Answer Image]

---

and I think I can initialize the value to `ActualRain` without declaring the 7th cell again, in other words, without writing: `WeatherListType[6] = new WeatherRecType();`

```
WeatherRecType[] WeatherListType = new WeatherRecType[10];
WeatherListType[6].ActualRain = 10;
```

Comment: `WeatherRecType[] WeatherListType = new WeatherRecType[10];` is better: the `[]` is part of the type, not the variable name. Both are allowed, however, as a token gesture to C programmers.

Comment: Seriously: by doing some more studying! That is super-basic stuff, document a zillion times out there; so you really should not come here first and ask for explanations ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your code snippet won't compile because `Class` (with a capital C) is not an actual keyword.

Comment: If I can give one more advice, avoid using capitals as the first letter of your variable names ; it's easily confounded with classes.

Comment: Concerning your screenshot : the code written here will not and will never compile if you write it this way, it needs to be encapsulated within a function, (such as `main`), but this is basic knowledge that you will acquire by studying more.

Comment: thanks @Ephi for the hint you gave me about "main function" and now my code works very well when I put it in main function.

Comment: *"and I think I can initialize the value to ActualRain without declaring the 7th cell again"* No you can't. Try to run your code, to see, that you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seventh record of an array in most basic programming languages (C, Java etc.) translates to index 6, as the counting begins with the index 0. So you would require:

```
WeatherListType[6] = new WeatherRecType();
WeatherListType[6].ActualRain = 1.05f;
```

But since this is a Data Structure course you are referring to, 7 may work if you are talking in terms of Pseudo code or something.

Comment: yes you are right because the array indexing starts from 0, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just write.

```
WeatherListType[7] = new WeatherRecType();
WeatherListType[7].ActualRain = 1.05f;
```

It is even better if you create setters for all fields in WeatherRecType.

Update : make the correction because of the comment below.

Comment: I don't think that this will work, as WeatherLidtType[7] will contain null in this case. You need to initialize it first.

Comment: For sure! Have missed it. Should be
`WeatherListType[7] = new WeatherRecType();
WeatherListType[7].ActualRain = 1.05f;`

Comment: The index is incorrect. The questions says "the seventh record", so the correct index is `6`.

Answer (score 0):

WeatherListType[6].ActualRain = 1.05f;